# Why is there a mistake in my replace function?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = np.linspace(-0.02, 0.02, 5)
print pd.Series([-0.02, 0.02, -0.01, 0.01, 0.02]).replace(x, np.arange(0, 5))
print pd.Series([-0.02, 0.02, -0.01, 0.01, 0.02]).replace([-0.02, -0.01, 0, 0.01, 0.02], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

**The outcome is:**

```
0      0.00  
1      4.00  
2      1.00  
3      0.01  
4      4.00
dtype: float64    

0      0  
1      4  
2      1  
3      3  
4      4  
dtype: float64
```

Why the replace function can't transform 0.01 to 3 in first print statement?

Comment: If you are comparing floating point numbers for equality, **you're gonna have a bad time.** i̶t̶ ̶m̶a̶y̶ ̶o̶r̶ ̶m̶a̶y̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶b̶l̶e̶m̶ ̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ It is the problem here.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is a floating point error in the creation of `x`. Its difficult to compare floating point numbers for equality like this

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-0.02, 0.02, 5)

print x
# [-0.02 -0.01  0.    0.01  0.02]

0.01 in x
# False

print x[3]
# 0.0099999999999999985

print x[4]
# 0.02
```